# Finding Smallest Number in Vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the smallest number in a vector, but my code is outputting 000 each time I run it.

I've tried looking at other questions on stack overflow, but it seems like others were not receiving a similar error to mine.

```
    cout << "The smallest number is: ";
    for (i = 0; i < numberList.size(); ++i) {
        int smallest = numberList.at(0);
        if (numberList.at(i) < smallest) {
            smallest = numberList.at(i);
            }
        cout << smallest;
        }
```

When I enter 3 numbers: 1 2 3 (as separate inputs)
I get that the smallest number is: 000

Comment: Look at your code. At the beginning of **every** iteration you reset `smallest` to be whatever is in slot `[0]` of your vector. It also prints that value out once per iteration rather than one value after. Finally, since you say this dumps zero (whihc is clearly not 1,2 or 3),  I'm inclined to believe the content of your `numberList` isn't what you  think either, the population code of which you didn't include. Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring smallest and outputting inside the loop so it will do that on every iteration, here you go:

```
std::cout << "The smallest number is: ";
int smallest = numberList.at(0);
for (int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); ++i) {

    if (numberList.at(i) < smallest) {
        smallest = numberList.at(i);
    }

}
std::cout << smallest;
```

If you're getting "0" your vector probably has 0 in it somewhere. But you'll need to post how you're creating it for that.

Also, you can also just use numberList[i], you don't need .at().

Answer (score 1):

You could use [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) which does precisely what you want.